# Reverse DNS not resolving for IPv6 addresses in BIND

Tags: bind, ipv6, reverse-dns

Reverse DNS entries for IPv6 addresses are not working. Everything I've read on the subject says the following configuration should work:

In named.conf:

```
zone "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.c.7.5.0.6.2.ip6.arpa" IN {
      type master;
      file "/var/lib/bind/ipv6reverse.hosts";
      allow-update { none; };
};
```

In /var/lib/bind/ipv6reverse.hosts:

```
$TTL 2d
$ORIGIN 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.c.7.5.0.6.2.IP6.ARPA.
@       IN      SOA     ns1.domain.ca.  hostmaster.domain.ca. (
            2011051104 ; serial
            1h      ; refresh
            1h      ; retry
            20d     ; expire
            2d      ; minimum
                            )
    IN      NS      ns1.domain.ca.
    IN      NS      ns2.domain.ca.

3.2.0.0.                IN      PTR     smtp.domain.ca.
```

When I try to do the reverse hostname lookup, I get the following error:

```
# host -6 2605:7c00:3::23 2605:7c00:3::11
Using domain server:
Name: 206.12.82.130
Address: ::ffff:206.12.82.130#53
Aliases: 

Host 3.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.c.7.5.0.6.2.ip6.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

As far as I can tell, this *should* be found.

The syslog for bind has some rather cryptic entries that may be related:

```
May 12 10:28:57 www3 named[16018]:   validating @0xb253cf10: . SOA: no valid signature found
May 12 10:28:57 www3 named[16018]:   validating @0xb253cf10: . NSEC: no valid signature found
May 12 10:28:57 www3 named[16018]:   validating @0xb253cf10: org NSEC: no valid signature found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh Grr! There was a . at the end of 3.2.0.0. I swear I tried this 6 times over. Stupid syntax errors.

Comment: Snigger.  IPv6 rDNS is a pain, isn't it.  I'm getting used to the look, but it's UGLY!  Since we can't subnet below a /64, why not have all the last 16 characters as one block rather than having to count dots?

Comment: Alternatively, we should all consider generating IPv6 rDNS programatically,e.g. using something like http://member.wide.ad.jp/~fujiwara/v6rev.html - this is much less error-prone than writing it out by hand.

Comment: Strange that I couldn't find that in Google. :) It wasn't from lack of trying either.